# Weird World of Warcraft OpenGL glitchyness

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl

When I start WoW it looks fine, but when I attempt to type my password the screen randomly zooms into the top left corner (like it triggering some Ubuntu function) and I have no idea why it does. It only does it in OpenGL mode, I really don't want to use DirectX since its constantly stutters.

---

OS: **Ubuntu 17.04 (32-bit)**

CPU: **AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5000+ × 2**

Graphics (Intergrated): **Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430**

Comment: Are you using the version of Wine in the archives?

Comment: I installed this way: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Comment: Nevermind, just fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by opening "**winecfg**" and by navigating to the "**Graphics**" pane and checking the following:

**Allow the window manager to decorate the windows** ☑

**Allow the windows manager to control the windows** ☑